# Flutter TabBar. How to change the padding

Tags: flutter, dart

Here's my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../widgets/profile_page/user_info.dart';
import '../widgets/profile_page/user_messages.dart';
import '../widgets/profile_page/user_multimedia.dart';
import '../widgets/profile_page/user_stats.dart';

class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _ProfilePageState createState() => _ProfilePageState();
}

class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  final List<Tab> _tabs = [
    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle), text: 'User Info',),
    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.chat_bubble), text: 'Messages',),
    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.photo_size_select_actual), text: 'Multimedia',),
    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.show_chart), text: 'Statistics',),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: DefaultTabController(
        length: 4,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("${_tabs[_currentIndex].text}"),
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: _tabs,
              onTap: (int index){
                setState(() {
                  _currentIndex = index;
                });
              },
              indicatorWeight: 3.0,
              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            children: <Widget>[
              UserInfo(),
              UserMessages(),
              UserMultimedia(),
              UserStats(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Can somebody tell me how can i remove padding around the Tab Bar icons? I already set the font size to 0, but it changed nothing. I would like to leave the text in Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle), text: 'User Info',) because i use it in appbar title: Text("${_tabs[_currentIndex].text}"), when the tabs change.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fvZ2.png)

Comment: Remove text in tab bar and create string list with your tab texts then use it like stringList[tab_index] !

Comment: Its an issue reported to `Flutter` so I think you need to make `CustomTabBar` for yourself. Here is the link: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21694

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the text parameter from tab bar.

It means replace

```
  final List<Tab> _tabs = [
    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle), text: 'User Info',),
    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.chat_bubble), text: 'Messages',),
    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.photo_size_select_actual), text: 'Multimedia',),
    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.show_chart), text: 'Statistics',),
  ];
```

to

```
final List<Tab> _tabs = [
    Tab(
      icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
    ),
    Tab(
      icon: Icon(Icons.chat_bubble),
    ),
    Tab(
      icon: Icon(Icons.photo_size_select_actual),
    ),
    Tab(
      icon: Icon(Icons.show_chart),
    ),
  ];
```

and it will work

Comment: I would like to leave the text in Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle), text: 'User Info',) because i use it in appbar title: Text("${_tabs[_currentIndex].text}"), when the tabs change.

Comment: +my solution
You can add another list that have the same ordered strings ['User Info','Messages',... etc] and use it at the AppBar

Comment: I thought about it, but i wanted to know if i can do it directly with TabBar.

Answer (score 0):

Use child property in Tab

like this:

from

```
Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle), text: 'User Info',),
```

to

```
Tab(child: Column( children: [ Icon(Icons.account_circle), Text("User Info"), ], )),
```